Having an issue installing MySQL using npm on a Mac
I am taking a class right now and working on an assignment. This is the first time I am working with database with Node js...
I am getting an error when trying to install...
What I am sending....
kylecross@Kyles-Mac-mini nodeSalesDB % sudo npm install mysql

The error I am getting...
npm error code E404
npm error 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mysql - Not found
npm error 404
npm error 404  'mysql@*' is not in this registry.
npm error 404
npm error 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm error 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/kylecross/.npm/_logs/2024-12-08T18_53_25_082Z-debug-0.log

Any help please?
I tried using mysql2 as well...but same issue.
I am expecting MySQL to be added.

Try specifying the version. "mysql@2.18.1".

if https://registry.npmjs.org/mysql is not found, then the issue is with your network

@TimRoberts, you are the man! Thank you, that worked.
